# How do I make two different designs XIB vertical and horizontal

Tags: iphone, xcode

Hi everyone I have a question with

I work with .xib, add buttons and other interface.
Faced with such a problem. While device in the upright position, all excellent, but as soon as I turn it all breaks down to hell. Given the interface of my program I was not able to flip it, I need to completely redraw it

My question is: How do I make two different designs XIB vertical and horizontal

p.s. My programa in vertical XIB looks

```
11|22 
33|44
55|66
```

In the horizontal XIN I need to, but I also need a new interface

```
11|22|33 
44|66|77
```

Answer (score 0):

In the IB

- Make sure the "Navigator" and "Utilities" Views are being displayed (In the "View" section in the top right of the main window.
- Select the "View" object in the Navigator column
- In the Utilities column, select the little icon that is 3rd from Rt.

There is an "Orientation" drop down that allows you to select Portrait and Landscape.

Let me know if that helps.

Comment: It works, all the images are rotated.
If I understand you correctly, then everything works.
My problem is that I need to use a different design for the horizontal. It differs from the vertical

Comment: One thing you can try. If you are using these images then add it from the code. and you can use CGRect to position them. Write two function. Make If and Else and position them. What do you think ?

Comment: So, too, does not come out. The fact that the different positioning is old pictures, and if fully integrated code to what then XIb =)

Comment: I am sorry, I badly write on English and use a translator =(

Comment: it is possible. Check this and let me know. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9661919/connect-two-xibs-to-one-viewcontroller